# (initramfs) Terminal - Instead of Ubuntu login screen

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, initramfs

I've been using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS normally, but today when I turned my laptop on, and selected Ubuntu out of two options: Windows and Ubuntu, the following screen appeared:

Here's snapshot of the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a filesystem error.You follow below steps it will help you sure:

1)Boot your machine with ubuntu live cd and select **try ubuntu**
2)Install Gparted application in it via internet
3)After installation open Gparted tool
4)Select your hard drive in Gparted tool and select first partition and right click and choose "check" option and then ok >> apply >> click on right symbol on top and done you have completed successfully.

5)Now boot your machine with your hard disk only.